# NSCollectionView - Core Data Binding - Does not display unless I resize the window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nscollectionview

While I have made great strides in customizing an NSCollectionView, thanks to hints I've gleamed here and across the web, I am having a bit of difficulty I'm hoping someone can help with. I have a Core Data entity that contains information about Video files and a NSCollectionView that displays a thumbnail image preview of each of these videos. I have bindings setup on the NSCollectionView.

On my first attempt at setting up bindings, I setup my Array Controller in Class mode and tied it's content to an NSMutableArray that I was filling with all of the objects from my Videos entity in windowDidLoad. I was performing addObject on the array controller to get them to show up. This works fine except for the fact that it takes quite a while if you have a lot of objects to load.

So... It seemed silly to me to copy all of the objects to an array when it's possible to bind a NSCollectionView directly to Core Data. I changed my ArrayController to Entity mode and setup the Managed Object Context to point to my App Delegate's managedObjectContext. When I launch my application, there is a delay before the Window displays on screen. In fact, the other things I'm doing in windowDidLoad process immediately, but it takes another 5-10 seconds for the window to display. Once it does, nothing is showing in the NSCollectionView.

I initially thought it just was not working until I accidentally resized the Window and all of the items showed up in the collection view. I've tried to see if there is a way to know when the Window is actually displayed so that I can call [collectionView setNeedsDisplay:YES] but either it doesn't work or I'm not calling it in the right place.

Does anyone have an idea why the objects are not just showing up? I'd also like for the Window to display immediately and then for the Collection View to load the items from the Core Data. Loading directly from Core Data seems much quicker than copying the items to an array. I'd be happy to post any code you'd like to see although since the bindings are setup in IB, there is not much to show. :)

Thanks!